# Baby Rudin Corollary Ch. 1

Tags: real-analysis

I know this is a very simple corollary, which is why it is so frustrating that I do not understand it. It states:

If a and b are positive real numbers and n is a positive integer, then $(ab)^{1/n}$$=a^{1/n}b^{1/b}$.

I understand why the proof wants to define alpha and beta as $a^{1/n}$ and $b^{1/n}$ but I do not understand why $\alpha^n \beta^n$=$(\alpha \beta)^n$ by the M2 property, which is that multiplication is commutative. Could someone please explain this to me? Why does this property allow us to lump exponents together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, in the case where $n = 2$, we have,
$$(\alpha \beta)^2 = (\alpha \beta)(\alpha \beta) = \alpha \beta\alpha \beta$$
On the other hand,
$$\alpha^2 \beta^2 = \alpha \alpha \beta\beta.$$
I challenge you to show that these are equal without commutative multiplication!

Comment: thank you! This actually makes a ton of sense now